# Filter Perforce History by User

Tags: perforce

Is there a way—either in P4V or command-line `p4`—to look through the History of a particular directory and show only changelists by a particular user/submitter?

<sub>*I thought older versions of P4V had this feature (though I can't be sure) and I cannot find anything relevant in the menus of the current P4V.*</sub>

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Though the History view—which is automatically filtered to the last-selected folder/file in the active tree view—does not seem to have the ability to filter, the Submitted Changelists view can be filtered by both User and file spec. Open the view with `Ctrl+2`, or from the View menu:

[image: View Menu]

and then specify the filter at the top of the "Submitted" tab:

[image: Filter showing user and file specification.]

Answer (score 9):

On the command line you want to combine the '-u ' and the path like so:

```
p4 changes -u someuser //depot/path/to/sources/...
```

You can further limit the output with the usual `revRange` syntax when specifying the path.